# Wrong div changes color when hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I have a really strange issue with some HTML I've been working with. I have two div that are each independent from each other. Although they both use the same CSS, each div has its own data inside it. I tried to create a "show more" button for each div, where clicking the button expands the div, and then changes the button text to "show less".
However, I have an issue where each div in a separate page works perfectly, but when both divs are in the same HTML page like I want them to be, hovering over the button has unintended side effects. Instead of each button changing color independently when hovered over (the first button turns gray when you hover over it, while the second turns maroon), hovering over the first button affects the color of the second button. Hovering over the second button also affects the color of the second button.
[This is a jsfiddle of the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/fz01ky87/2/)
Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#period1").ready(function() {
        showall = $("#period1 .showallbutton");
        classgrade = $("#period1 .head tr .grade b");
        footbar = $("#period1 .foot");
        headbar = $("#period1 .head");
        gtbar = $("#period1 .gradestopbar");
        elementshidden = $("#period1 .grades tr:not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)):not(:first-child)");
        percentcolumn = $("#period1 .grades tr td:nth-child(5)");
        eccolumn = $("#period1 .grades tr td:nth-child(6) center");
        percentcolumn.each(function() {
          elem = $(this)
          percent = $(this).text();
          percentfloat = parseFloat(percent)
          if (percentfloat <= 69.9) {
            elem.parent().css("color", "#DD0000");
          } else if (percentfloat >= 70 && percentfloat <= 84.9) {
            elem.parent().css("color", "#000000");
          } else if (percentfloat >= 85) {
            elem.parent().css("color", "#00bb00")
          }
        });
        eccolumn.each(function() {
          elem = $(this)
          eccheckmark = elem.text();
          if (eccheckmark === "✔") {
            elem.parent().parent().css("color", "#008FFF")
          }
        });
        if (classgrade.text()[0] === "A" || classgrade.text() === "B+") {
          headbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
          gtbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
          footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
          showall.hover(function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#008FFF99");
          }, function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
          });
        } else if (classgrade.text()[0] === "D" || classgrade.text()[0] === "F") {
          headbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          gtbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          showall.hover(function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#AA0000");
          }, function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          });
        } else {
          headbar.css("background-color", "black");
          gtbar.css("background-color", "black");
          footbar.css("background-color", "black");
          showall.css("color", "white")
          showall.hover(function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "gray");
          }, function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "black");
          });
        }
        showall.click(function() {
          if (elementshidden.css("display") === "table-row") {
            elementshidden.hide();
            showall.text("Show More")
          } else if (elementshidden.css("display") === "none") {
            elementshidden.show();
            showall.text("Show Less");
          }
        });
      });
    $("#period2").ready(function() {
      showall = $("#period2 .showallbutton");
      classgrade = $("#period2 .head tr .grade b");
      footbar = $("#period2 .foot");
      headbar = $("#period2 .head");
      gtbar = $("#period2 .gradestopbar");
      elementshidden = $("#period2 .grades tr:not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)):not(:first-child)");
      percentcolumn = $("#period2 .grades tr td:nth-child(5)");
      eccolumn = $("#period2 .grades tr td:nth-child(6) center");
      percentcolumn.each(function() {
        elem = $(this)
        percent = $(this).text();
        percentfloat = parseFloat(percent)
        if (percentfloat <= 69.9) {
          elem.parent().css("color", "#DD0000");
        } else if (percentfloat >= 70 && percentfloat <= 84.9) {
          elem.parent().css("color", "#000000");
        } else if (percentfloat >= 85) {
          elem.parent().css("color", "#00bb00")
        }
      });
      eccolumn.each(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().css("color", "#008FFF")
      });
      if (classgrade.text()[0] === "A" || classgrade.text() === "B+") {
        headbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
        gtbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
        footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
        showall.hover(function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#008FFF99");
        }, function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
        });
      } else if (classgrade.text()[0] === "D" || classgrade.text()[0] === "F") {
        headbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        gtbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        showall.hover(function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#AA0000");
        }, function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        });
      } else {
        headbar.css("background-color", "black");
        gtbar.css("background-color", "black");
        footbar.css("background-color", "black");
        showall.css("color", "white")
        showall.hover(function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "gray");
        }, function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "black");
        });
      }
      showall.click(function() {
        if (elementshidden.css("display") === "table-row") {
          elementshidden.hide();
          showall.text("Show More")
        } else if (elementshidden.css("display") === "none") {
          elementshidden.show();
          showall.text("Show Less");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
    body {
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    .maincontainer {
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .grades {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    }

    .grades td, .grades th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    .grades tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .grades tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: black;
    }

    .grades tr:not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)) {
      display: none;
    }

    .grades tr:first-child {
      display: table-row;
    }

    .grades tr:not(.gradestopbar):hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .grades th {
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .gradestopbar {
      border-top: 0.5px solid black;
      color: white;
    }

    .gradestopbar th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .datedue {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .assigned {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .assignment {
      width: 32%;
    }

    .scorefraction {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .scorepercent {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .extracreditcheckbox {
      width: 8%;
    }

    .notgradedcheckbox {
      width: 8%;
    }

    .head {
      border-collapse: separate;
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 50px;
      border-top-right-radius: 50px;
      border-top: 2px solid black;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
    }

    .head th {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      color: white;
    }

    .foot {
      font-size: 27px;
      border-collapse: separate;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .showallbutton {
      height: 40px;
      width: 60%;
      border: none;
      background-color: white;
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .showallbutton:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }

    .grade {
      font-size: 27px;
      width: 10%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .course {
      font-size: 24px;
      width: 45%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .teacher {
      font-size: 24px;
      padding-right: 50px;
      width: 45%;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="period1" class="maincontainer">
    <table class="head" width=1500px>
      <tr>
        <th class="course">
          Period 1: <b>Adv Mathemagic II</b>
        </th>
        <th class="grade">
          <b>B-</b>
        </th>
        <th class="teacher">
          <b>Johnson, John</b>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="grades">
      <tr class="gradestopbar">
        <th class="datedue">
          <label>
       Date Due
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assigned">
          <label>
       Assigned
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assignment">
          <label>
       Assignment
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorefraction">
          <label>
        Score
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorepercent">
          <label>
        Percent
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="extracreditcheckbox">
          <label>
       Extra
       <br>
       Credit
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="notgradedcheckbox">
          <label>
       Not
       <br>
       Graded
      </label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/20/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/20/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Mathemagic Practical Exam
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>87</sup>&#8260;<sub>100</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          87%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

          01/21/2018

        </td>
        <td>

          01/21/2018

        </td>
        <td>

          Participation

        </td>
        <td>

          <sup>15</sup>&#8260;<sub>30</sub>

        </td>
        <td>

          50%

        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Credit Assignment
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>5</sup>&#8260;<sub>5</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>✔</center>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Graphing
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>1</sup>&#8260;<sub>1</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 1
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 2
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>2</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          66.6%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 3
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 4
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 5
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
            ✔
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 6
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="foot">
      <tr class="showall">
        <td>
          <button class="showallbutton">Show More</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
    <div id="period2" class="maincontainer">
    <table class="head" width=1500px>
      <tr>
        <th class="course">
          Period 2: <b>Honors PE 5</b>
        </th>
        <th class="grade">
          <b>F</b>
        </th>
        <th class="teacher">
          <b>Daveson, Dave</b>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="grades">
      <tr class="gradestopbar">
        <th class="datedue">
          <label>
       Date Due
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assigned">
          <label>
       Assigned
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assignment">
          <label>
       Assignment
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorefraction">
          <label>
        Score
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorepercent">
          <label>
        Percent
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="extracreditcheckbox">
          <label>
       Extra
       <br>
       Credit
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="notgradedcheckbox">
          <label>
       Not
       <br>
       Graded
      </label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/01/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/01/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Volleyball Bouncing Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>12</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          60%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/21/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/21/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          January Participation
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>30</sup>&#8260;<sub>30</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Basketball into Trashcan Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>18</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          90%
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>✔</center>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Track and Field Sprinting Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>1</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          5%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          February Participation
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
            ✔
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Swimming Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>15</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          75%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          GSW Extra Credit
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>4</sup>&#8260;<sub>5</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          80%
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
            ✔
          </center>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="foot">
      <tr class="showall">
        <td>
          <button class="showallbutton">Show More</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

You can see that when you move your cursor over the first button, it changes the color of the second button without affecting the first button. Essentially, the first "show more" button only works as a button to control the second div. It doesn't do anything to the div it is supposed to be working for. Once again, both of the divs work correctly when they are in their own HTML files, but fail when put together.

Thanks in advance!

Note: All of the info in the html is fake, and has been substituted to protect privacy. But I don't believe that that is the reason for any issues.

Comment: Isnt this a lot of code for us to read?

Comment: That's what the fiddle is there for.

Comment: I wasn't too sure how to cut down the code without screwing it up, because I'm not really that good at html or JavaScript. Forgive me if there's a lot of useless stuff in there.

Comment: Ref: *"That's what the fiddle is there for"*. The fiddle is to provide means to reproduce the issue using the least amount of code possible. A.k.a [mcve]. Not doing so shows a lack of research and lack of respect for everyone else's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that all your variables like `showall`, `classgrade` etc are global variables. So the `hover` event handler gets attached to proper button, but by the time hover event is triggered, the `footbar` variable is referring to the `footbar` inside `#period2` and the effect gets applied on the bottom button.

All you need to do is declare local variables in the function as shown below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#period1").ready(function() {
        var showall = $("#period1 .showallbutton");
        var classgrade = $("#period1 .head tr .grade b");
        var footbar = $("#period1 .foot");
        var headbar = $("#period1 .head");
        var gtbar = $("#period1 .gradestopbar");
        var elementshidden = $("#period1 .grades tr:not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)):not(:first-child)");
        var percentcolumn = $("#period1 .grades tr td:nth-child(5)");
        var eccolumn = $("#period1 .grades tr td:nth-child(6) center");
        percentcolumn.each(function() {
          elem = $(this)
          percent = $(this).text();
          percentfloat = parseFloat(percent)
          if (percentfloat <= 69.9) {
            elem.parent().css("color", "#DD0000");
          } else if (percentfloat >= 70 && percentfloat <= 84.9) {
            elem.parent().css("color", "#000000");
          } else if (percentfloat >= 85) {
            elem.parent().css("color", "#00bb00")
          }
        });
        eccolumn.each(function() {
          elem = $(this)
          eccheckmark = elem.text();
          if (eccheckmark === "✔") {
            elem.parent().parent().css("color", "#008FFF")
          }
        });
        if (classgrade.text()[0] === "A" || classgrade.text() === "B+") {
          headbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
          gtbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
          footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
          showall.hover(function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#008FFF99");
          }, function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
          });
        } else if (classgrade.text()[0] === "D" || classgrade.text()[0] === "F") {
          headbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          gtbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          showall.hover(function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#AA0000");
          }, function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          });
        } else {
          headbar.css("background-color", "black");
          gtbar.css("background-color", "black");
          footbar.css("background-color", "black");
          showall.css("color", "white")
          showall.hover(function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "gray");
          }, function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "black");
          });
        }
        showall.click(function() {
          if (elementshidden.css("display") === "table-row") {
            elementshidden.hide();
            showall.text("Show More")
          } else if (elementshidden.css("display") === "none") {
            elementshidden.show();
            showall.text("Show Less");
          }
        });
      });
    $("#period2").ready(function() {
      var showall = $("#period2 .showallbutton");
      var classgrade = $("#period2 .head tr .grade b");
      var footbar = $("#period2 .foot");
      var headbar = $("#period2 .head");
      var gtbar = $("#period2 .gradestopbar");
      var elementshidden = $("#period2 .grades tr:not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)):not(:first-child)");
      var percentcolumn = $("#period2 .grades tr td:nth-child(5)");
      var eccolumn = $("#period2 .grades tr td:nth-child(6) center");
      percentcolumn.each(function() {
        elem = $(this)
        percent = $(this).text();
        percentfloat = parseFloat(percent)
        if (percentfloat <= 69.9) {
          elem.parent().css("color", "#DD0000");
        } else if (percentfloat >= 70 && percentfloat <= 84.9) {
          elem.parent().css("color", "#000000");
        } else if (percentfloat >= 85) {
          elem.parent().css("color", "#00bb00")
        }
      });
      eccolumn.each(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().css("color", "#008FFF")
      });
      if (classgrade.text()[0] === "A" || classgrade.text() === "B+") {
        headbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
        gtbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
        footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
        showall.hover(function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#008FFF99");
        }, function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
        });
      } else if (classgrade.text()[0] === "D" || classgrade.text()[0] === "F") {
        headbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        gtbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        showall.hover(function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#AA0000");
        }, function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        });
      } else {
        headbar.css("background-color", "black");
        gtbar.css("background-color", "black");
        footbar.css("background-color", "black");
        showall.css("color", "white")
        showall.hover(function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "gray");
        }, function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "black");
        });
      }
      showall.click(function() {
        if (elementshidden.css("display") === "table-row") {
          elementshidden.hide();
          showall.text("Show More")
        } else if (elementshidden.css("display") === "none") {
          elementshidden.show();
          showall.text("Show Less");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
    body {
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    .maincontainer {
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .grades {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    }

    .grades td, .grades th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    .grades tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .grades tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: black;
    }

    .grades tr:not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)) {
      display: none;
    }

    .grades tr:first-child {
      display: table-row;
    }

    .grades tr:not(.gradestopbar):hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .grades th {
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .gradestopbar {
      border-top: 0.5px solid black;
      color: white;
    }

    .gradestopbar th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .datedue {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .assigned {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .assignment {
      width: 32%;
    }

    .scorefraction {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .scorepercent {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .extracreditcheckbox {
      width: 8%;
    }

    .notgradedcheckbox {
      width: 8%;
    }

    .head {
      border-collapse: separate;
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 50px;
      border-top-right-radius: 50px;
      border-top: 2px solid black;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
    }

    .head th {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      color: white;
    }

    .foot {
      font-size: 27px;
      border-collapse: separate;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .showallbutton {
      height: 40px;
      width: 60%;
      border: none;
      background-color: white;
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .showallbutton:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }

    .grade {
      font-size: 27px;
      width: 10%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .course {
      font-size: 24px;
      width: 45%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .teacher {
      font-size: 24px;
      padding-right: 50px;
      width: 45%;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="period1" class="maincontainer">
    <table class="head" width=1500px>
      <tr>
        <th class="course">
          Period 1: <b>Adv Mathemagic II</b>
        </th>
        <th class="grade">
          <b>B-</b>
        </th>
        <th class="teacher">
          <b>Johnson, John</b>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="grades">
      <tr class="gradestopbar">
        <th class="datedue">
          <label>
       Date Due
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assigned">
          <label>
       Assigned
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assignment">
          <label>
       Assignment
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorefraction">
          <label>
        Score
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorepercent">
          <label>
        Percent
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="extracreditcheckbox">
          <label>
       Extra
       <br>
       Credit
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="notgradedcheckbox">
          <label>
       Not
       <br>
       Graded
      </label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/20/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/20/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Mathemagic Practical Exam
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>87</sup>&#8260;<sub>100</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          87%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

          01/21/2018

        </td>
        <td>

          01/21/2018

        </td>
        <td>

          Participation

        </td>
        <td>

          <sup>15</sup>&#8260;<sub>30</sub>

        </td>
        <td>

          50%

        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Credit Assignment
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>5</sup>&#8260;<sub>5</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>✔</center>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Graphing
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>1</sup>&#8260;<sub>1</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 1
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 2
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>2</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          66.6%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 3
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 4
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 5
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
            ✔
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 6
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="foot">
      <tr class="showall">
        <td>
          <button class="showallbutton">Show More</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
    <div id="period2" class="maincontainer">
    <table class="head" width=1500px>
      <tr>
        <th class="course">
          Period 2: <b>Honors PE 5</b>
        </th>
        <th class="grade">
          <b>F</b>
        </th>
        <th class="teacher">
          <b>Daveson, Dave</b>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="grades">
      <tr class="gradestopbar">
        <th class="datedue">
          <label>
       Date Due
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assigned">
          <label>
       Assigned
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assignment">
          <label>
       Assignment
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorefraction">
          <label>
        Score
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorepercent">
          <label>
        Percent
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="extracreditcheckbox">
          <label>
       Extra
       <br>
       Credit
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="notgradedcheckbox">
          <label>
       Not
       <br>
       Graded
      </label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/01/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/01/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Volleyball Bouncing Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>12</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          60%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/21/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/21/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          January Participation
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>30</sup>&#8260;<sub>30</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Basketball into Trashcan Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>18</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          90%
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>✔</center>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Track and Field Sprinting Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>1</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          5%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          February Participation
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
            ✔
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Swimming Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>15</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          75%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          GSW Extra Credit
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>4</sup>&#8260;<sub>5</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          80%
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
            ✔
          </center>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="foot">
      <tr class="showall">
        <td>
          <button class="showallbutton">Show More</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a lot of code to look through, but I see your problem. You're referencing the two buttons based off the `showAll` class. Since the both have the same class, the hover event gets called for each button.

You need to give each button an id of `topButton` and `bottomButton`.

From there you can directly access each button individually using:

```
document.getElementById("topButton")
```

Use `.style` to change the CSS of each button.

Comment: So each button needs a separate id?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes, you will also need to update your js events

Comment: @Joe Not really. No need for separate IDs for each button because @BruceWayne is using specific selector like `$("#period1 .showallbutton");`. So the `.showallbutton` inside `#period1` is going to get selected not the other one.

Comment: @Joe, this isn't the issue, the css selectorw are properly placed `"#period1 .showallbutton"`, `"#period2 .showallbutton"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have different variables in your `ready` functions. The way you are declaring your variables makes them globally scoped and that's your problem there. I've made very little changes, you'll want to finish this, declaring your variables with `const`, `let` or `var` keyword

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#period1").ready(function() {
        const showall = $("#period1 .showallbutton");
        const classgrade = $("#period1 .head tr .grade b");
        const footbar = $("#period1 .foot");
        const headbar = $("#period1 .head");
        const gtbar = $("#period1 .gradestopbar");
        const elementshidden = $("#period1 .grades tr:not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)):not(:first-child)");
        const percentcolumn = $("#period1 .grades tr td:nth-child(5)");
        const eccolumn = $("#period1 .grades tr td:nth-child(6) center");
        percentcolumn.each(function() {
          elem = $(this)
          percent = $(this).text();
          percentfloat = parseFloat(percent)
          if (percentfloat <= 69.9) {
            elem.parent().css("color", "#DD0000");
          } else if (percentfloat >= 70 && percentfloat <= 84.9) {
            elem.parent().css("color", "#000000");
          } else if (percentfloat >= 85) {
            elem.parent().css("color", "#00bb00")
          }
        });
        eccolumn.each(function() {
          elem = $(this)
          eccheckmark = elem.text();
          if (eccheckmark === "✔") {
            elem.parent().parent().css("color", "#008FFF")
          }
        });
        if (classgrade.text()[0] === "A" || classgrade.text() === "B+") {
          headbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
          gtbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
          footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
          showall.hover(function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#008FFF99");
          }, function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
          });
        } else if (classgrade.text()[0] === "D" || classgrade.text()[0] === "F") {
          headbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          gtbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          showall.hover(function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#AA0000");
          }, function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
          });
        } else {
          headbar.css("background-color", "black");
          gtbar.css("background-color", "black");
          footbar.css("background-color", "black");
          showall.css("color", "white")
          showall.hover(function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "gray");
          }, function() {
            footbar.css({
              "transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
              "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
            });
            footbar.css("background-color", "black");
          });
        }
        showall.click(function() {
          if (elementshidden.css("display") === "table-row") {
            elementshidden.hide();
            showall.text("Show More")
          } else if (elementshidden.css("display") === "none") {
            elementshidden.show();
            showall.text("Show Less");
          }
        });
      });
    $("#period2").ready(function() {
      showall = $("#period2 .showallbutton");
      classgrade = $("#period2 .head tr .grade b");
      footbar = $("#period2 .foot");
      headbar = $("#period2 .head");
      gtbar = $("#period2 .gradestopbar");
      elementshidden = $("#period2 .grades tr:not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)):not(:first-child)");
      percentcolumn = $("#period2 .grades tr td:nth-child(5)");
      eccolumn = $("#period2 .grades tr td:nth-child(6) center");
      percentcolumn.each(function() {
        elem = $(this)
        percent = $(this).text();
        percentfloat = parseFloat(percent)
        if (percentfloat <= 69.9) {
          elem.parent().css("color", "#DD0000");
        } else if (percentfloat >= 70 && percentfloat <= 84.9) {
          elem.parent().css("color", "#000000");
        } else if (percentfloat >= 85) {
          elem.parent().css("color", "#00bb00")
        }
      });
      eccolumn.each(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().css("color", "#008FFF")
      });
      if (classgrade.text()[0] === "A" || classgrade.text() === "B+") {
        headbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
        gtbar.css("background-color", "#1EC53A");
        footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
        showall.hover(function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#008FFF99");
        }, function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#1A9AFF")
        });
      } else if (classgrade.text()[0] === "D" || classgrade.text()[0] === "F") {
        headbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        gtbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        showall.hover(function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#AA0000");
        }, function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "#DD0000");
        });
      } else {
        headbar.css("background-color", "black");
        gtbar.css("background-color", "black");
        footbar.css("background-color", "black");
        showall.css("color", "white")
        showall.hover(function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "gray");
        }, function() {
          footbar.css({
            "transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-webkit-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-o-transition": "all 0.5s",
            "-moz-transition": "all 0.5s"
          });
          footbar.css("background-color", "black");
        });
      }
      showall.click(function() {
        if (elementshidden.css("display") === "table-row") {
          elementshidden.hide();
          showall.text("Show More")
        } else if (elementshidden.css("display") === "none") {
          elementshidden.show();
          showall.text("Show Less");
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

```css
    body {
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    .maincontainer {
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .grades {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    }

    .grades td, .grades th {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    .grades tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .grades tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: black;
    }

    .grades tr:not(:nth-last-child(-n+5)) {
      display: none;
    }

    .grades tr:first-child {
      display: table-row;
    }

    .grades tr:not(.gradestopbar):hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .grades th {
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .gradestopbar {
      border-top: 0.5px solid black;
      color: white;
    }

    .gradestopbar th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .datedue {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .assigned {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .assignment {
      width: 32%;
    }

    .scorefraction {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .scorepercent {
      width: 13%;
    }

    .extracreditcheckbox {
      width: 8%;
    }

    .notgradedcheckbox {
      width: 8%;
    }

    .head {
      border-collapse: separate;
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 50px;
      border-top-right-radius: 50px;
      border-top: 2px solid black;
      border-left: 2px solid black;
      border-right: 2px solid black;
      border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
    }

    .head th {
      padding-top: 12px;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      color: white;
    }

    .foot {
      font-size: 27px;
      border-collapse: separate;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }

    .showallbutton {
      height: 40px;
      width: 60%;
      border: none;
      background-color: white;
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .showallbutton:focus {
      outline: 0;
    }

    .grade {
      font-size: 27px;
      width: 10%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .course {
      font-size: 24px;
      width: 45%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .teacher {
      font-size: 24px;
      padding-right: 50px;
      width: 45%;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="period1" class="maincontainer">
    <table class="head" width=1500px>
      <tr>
        <th class="course">
          Period 1: <b>Adv Mathemagic II</b>
        </th>
        <th class="grade">
          <b>B-</b>
        </th>
        <th class="teacher">
          <b>Johnson, John</b>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="grades">
      <tr class="gradestopbar">
        <th class="datedue">
          <label>
       Date Due
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assigned">
          <label>
       Assigned
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assignment">
          <label>
       Assignment
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorefraction">
          <label>
        Score
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorepercent">
          <label>
        Percent
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="extracreditcheckbox">
          <label>
       Extra
       <br>
       Credit
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="notgradedcheckbox">
          <label>
       Not
       <br>
       Graded
      </label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/20/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/20/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Mathemagic Practical Exam
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>87</sup>&#8260;<sub>100</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          87%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>

          01/21/2018

        </td>
        <td>

          01/21/2018

        </td>
        <td>

          Participation

        </td>
        <td>

          <sup>15</sup>&#8260;<sub>30</sub>

        </td>
        <td>

          50%

        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Credit Assignment
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>5</sup>&#8260;<sub>5</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>✔</center>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Graphing
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>1</sup>&#8260;<sub>1</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 1
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 2
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>2</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          66.6%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 3
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 4
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 5
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
            ✔
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Extra Assignment 6
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>3</sup>&#8260;<sub>3</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="foot">
      <tr class="showall">
        <td>
          <button class="showallbutton">Show More</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
    <div id="period2" class="maincontainer">
    <table class="head" width=1500px>
      <tr>
        <th class="course">
          Period 2: <b>Honors PE 5</b>
        </th>
        <th class="grade">
          <b>F</b>
        </th>
        <th class="teacher">
          <b>Daveson, Dave</b>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="grades">
      <tr class="gradestopbar">
        <th class="datedue">
          <label>
       Date Due
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assigned">
          <label>
       Assigned
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="assignment">
          <label>
       Assignment
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorefraction">
          <label>
        Score
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="scorepercent">
          <label>
        Percent
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="extracreditcheckbox">
          <label>
       Extra
       <br>
       Credit
      </label>
        </th>
        <th class="notgradedcheckbox">
          <label>
       Not
       <br>
       Graded
      </label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/01/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/01/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Volleyball Bouncing Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>12</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          60%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/21/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/21/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          January Participation
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>30</sup>&#8260;<sub>30</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          100%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Basketball into Trashcan Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>18</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          90%
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>✔</center>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/22/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Track and Field Sprinting Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>1</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          5%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          February Participation
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
            ✔
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          Swimming Test
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>15</sup>&#8260;<sub>20</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          75%
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          01/23/2018
        </td>
        <td>
          GSW Extra Credit
        </td>
        <td>
          <sup>4</sup>&#8260;<sub>5</sub>
        </td>
        <td>
          80%
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
            ✔
          </center>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="foot">
      <tr class="showall">
        <td>
          <button class="showallbutton">Show More</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```